# wrongly deleted answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer, vote-to-undelete

Can a moderator please undelete my answer to this question?

[How to query WURFL information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184560/how-to-query-wurfl-information)

It is 100% relevant

Comment: You may want to explain that you already made it clear in the answer you work for the company (so it is not spam or overt self-promotion). I suspect that it was flagged as such and that is why the moderator deleted it.

Comment: The *normal* procedure is to flag the post for moderator attention and request an undelete, btw.

Comment: I note that your answer doesn't really address the question though. As such it does come over as spam.

Comment: @Luca, if I may add, it appears you have posted off-topic answers in the past to defend your product ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22978666/464709)). This is not a good use of answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Creating multiple accounts to post the same spam answers to the same questions isn't exactly helping your case either.  Looking through your other answers, it appears as if the entire purpose of your account here is to advertise your product.  That is a violation of the site's rules.  (Even *if* you're posts disclose your affiliation.)

Comment: so, let me get this right, should I disclose my affiliation or should I not disclose my affiliation in my posts?
I argue that my answer does answer the question (definitely for some use cases, even though not all).
Multiple accounts for Spam answers? not sure what you are talking about...

Answer (score 6):

I think that particular, specific answer *is* OK for the question that was asked, and I am restoring it. However, I am not sure about what will happen to the *question* itself. I'm not going to take any action on it, but if someone had posted that question today, I would not hesitate to put it on hold.

---

That said, we (another moderator, a Community Manager, and myself) have exchanged numerous messages with you about the activity on your account. One of the last things I told you a couple days ago was that you should put in a moderator flag on any posts you would like reviewed to be opened. I also suggested you consider editing your posts to be more appropriate to the specific question before doing so. While posting on Meta can have the desired effect (as it is here), it's not really how you should do this in general. If you have more you'd like restored, please follow the advice I sent you privately.

As others have noted, though, you do seem to have a clear pattern. I am not immediately aware of any post you have that does not promote your products/services, and that includes the... non-trivial... number of deleted answers you have - and over both of the accounts of yours which have posted on that question. As we have noted in our messages to you:

> Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons.

This pattern has been borne out with both your history of comments and even edits. In fact, the only body of content you have submitted here I can find that is not promotional is getting in... spirited... discussions with others about your product compared to others, or the actual terms of the licensing.

As I told you in our messages, I have a good bit of respect for your obvious ability and the apparent quality of your company's products. I think you could be a *superb* contributor to Stack Overflow, and I think that would bring you more positive attention to your products/services than what you have been doing. I hope we can work out the apparent misunderstandings here. But to reiterate; please put in a moderator "other" flag for that, and take a couple minutes to consider if the answer could be improved.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I have to admit that I wasn't aware of the complex net of rules that govern the management of SO. I will do my best to improve. Is it me or are the rules so complex that one can always find something to support any decision and its opposite?